# Opencart 3.0 Show Customer First Name in Header

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I am trying to add customer first name in header but its not working. I have taken the reference from https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=202&t=199425&p=702133&hilit=bug+%25s#p702133 . The Problem is the output is showing as **Welcome %s**. The following is the code of controller header.php :

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
public function index() {
    // Analytics
    $this->load->model('setting/extension');

    $data['analytics'] = array();

    $analytics = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('analytics');

    foreach ($analytics as $analytic) {
        if ($this->config->get('analytics_' . $analytic['code'] . '_status')) {
            $data['analytics'][] = $this->load->controller('extension/analytics/' . $analytic['code'], $this->config->get('analytics_' . $analytic['code'] . '_status'));
        }
    }

    if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
        $server = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
    } else {
        $server = $this->config->get('config_url');
    }

    if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_icon'))) {
        $this->document->addLink($server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_icon'), 'icon');
    }

    $data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle();


    $data['base'] = $server;
    $data['description'] = $this->document->getDescription();
    $data['keywords'] = $this->document->getKeywords();
    $data['links'] = $this->document->getLinks();
    $data['styles'] = $this->document->getStyles();
    $data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts('header');
    $data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code');
    $data['direction'] = $this->language->get('direction');

    $data['name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');

    if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_logo'))) {
        $data['logo'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
    } else {
        $data['logo'] = '';
    }

    $this->load->language('common/header');

    // Wishlist
    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->load->model('account/wishlist');


        $data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), $this->model_account_wishlist->getTotalWishlist());
    } else {
        $data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) ? count($this->session->data['wishlist']) : 0));
    }


     $this->load->model('account/customer_group');

        $customer_group = $this->model_account_customer_group->getCustomerGroup($this->config->get('config_customer_group_id'));

/*  $data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', true), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true));*/
    $data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', true), $this->customer->getfirstName(),  $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true));
    $data['home'] = $this->url->link('common/home');
    $data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', true);
    $data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
    $data['customertitle'] = "Welcome";
        $data['customer_firstname'] = html_entity_decode($this->customer->getfirstName(), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    $data['customer_lastname'] = $this->customer->getLastName();

    $data['account'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', true);
    $data['register'] = $this->url->link('account/register', '', true);
    $data['login'] = $this->url->link('account/login', '', true);
    /*$data['customer_firstname']=$this->customer->getFirstName();*/
    $data['order'] = $this->url->link('account/order', '', true);
    $data['transaction'] = $this->url->link('account/transaction', '', true);
    $data['download'] = $this->url->link('account/download', '', true);
    $data['logout'] = $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true);
    $data['shopping_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
    $data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true);
    $data['contact'] = $this->url->link('information/contact');
    $data['telephone'] = $this->config->get('config_telephone');

    /*$data['firstname']=$this->load->controller('common/firstname');*/
    $data['language'] = $this->load->controller('common/language');
    $data['currency'] = $this->load->controller('common/currency');
    $data['search'] = $this->load->controller('common/search');
    $data['cart'] = $this->load->controller('common/cart');
    $data['menu'] = $this->load->controller('common/menu');



    return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
 }
}
```

And the language file code is as follow :

```
<?php
  // Text
$_['text_home']          = 'Home';
$_['text_wishlist']      = 'Wish List (%s)';
$_['text_shopping_cart'] = 'Shopping Cart';
$_['text_category']      = 'Categories';
$_['text_account']       = 'My Account';
$_['text_register']      = 'Register';
$_['text_login']         = 'Login';
$_['text_order']         = 'Order History';
$_['text_transaction']   = 'Transactions';
$_['text_download']      = 'Downloads';
$_['text_logout']        = 'Logout';
$_['text_checkout']      = 'Checkout';
$_['text_search']        = 'Search';
$_['text_all']           = 'Show All';
$_['text_customer_name'] = 'Hi %s %s';
$_['text_logged'] = '<a href="%s">Welcome %s</a> <a href="%s">Logout</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the following code on Opencart 3.0.2.0 and it works perfectly

The Header controller (catalog/controller/common/header.php)

```
<?php 
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
public function index() {
    // Analytics
    $this->load->model('setting/extension');

    $data['analytics'] = array();

    $analytics = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('analytics');

    foreach ($analytics as $analytic) {
        if ($this->config->get('analytics_' . $analytic['code'] . '_status')) {
            $data['analytics'][] = $this->load->controller('extension/analytics/' . $analytic['code'], $this->config->get('analytics_' . $analytic['code'] . '_status'));
        }
    }



    if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
        $server = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
    } else {
        $server = $this->config->get('config_url');
    }

    if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_icon'))) {
        $this->document->addLink($server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_icon'), 'icon');
    }

    $data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle();

    $data['base'] = $server;
    $data['description'] = $this->document->getDescription();
    $data['keywords'] = $this->document->getKeywords();
    $data['links'] = $this->document->getLinks();
    $data['styles'] = $this->document->getStyles();
    $data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts('header');
    $data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code');
    $data['direction'] = $this->language->get('direction');

    $data['name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');

    if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_logo'))) {
        $data['logo'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
    } else {
        $data['logo'] = '';
    }

    $this->load->language('common/header');

    // Wishlist
    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->load->model('account/wishlist');

        $data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), $this->model_account_wishlist->getTotalWishlist());
    } else {
        $data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) ? count($this->session->data['wishlist']) : 0));
    }

    $data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', true), $this->customer->getfirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true));

    $data['home'] = $this->url->link('common/home');
    $data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', true);
    $data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
    $data['account'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', true);
    $data['register'] = $this->url->link('account/register', '', true);
    $data['login'] = $this->url->link('account/login', '', true);
    $data['order'] = $this->url->link('account/order', '', true);
    $data['transaction'] = $this->url->link('account/transaction', '', true);
    $data['download'] = $this->url->link('account/download', '', true);
    $data['logout'] = $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true);
    $data['shopping_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
    $data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true);
    $data['contact'] = $this->url->link('information/contact');
    $data['telephone'] = $this->config->get('config_telephone');

    $data['language'] = $this->load->controller('common/language');
    $data['currency'] = $this->load->controller('common/currency');
    $data['search'] = $this->load->controller('common/search');
    $data['cart'] = $this->load->controller('common/cart');
    $data['menu'] = $this->load->controller('common/menu');

    return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
}
}
```

The Language file (catalog/language/common/header.php)

```
<?php
// Text
$_['text_home']          = 'Home';
$_['text_wishlist']      = 'Wish List (%s)';
$_['text_shopping_cart'] = 'Shopping Cart';
$_['text_category']      = 'Categories';
$_['text_account']       = 'My Account';
$_['text_register']      = 'Register';
$_['text_login']         = 'Login';
$_['text_order']         = 'Order History';
$_['text_transaction']   = 'Transactions';
$_['text_download']      = 'Downloads';
$_['text_logout']        = 'Logout';
$_['text_checkout']      = 'Checkout';
$_['text_search']        = 'Search';
$_['text_all']           = 'Show All';
$_['text_logged']        = '<a href="%s">Welcome %s</a><a href="%s">Logout</a>';
```

The Header view (catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.twig)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html dir="{{ direction }}" lang="{{ lang }}" class="ie8>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html dir="{{ direction }}" lang="{{ lang }}" class="ie9>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html dir="{{ direction }}" lang="{{ lang }}">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<base href="{{ base }}" />
{% if description %}
<meta name="description" content="{{ description }}" />
{% endif %}
{% if keywords %}
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ keywords }}" />
{% endif %}
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% for style in styles %}
<link href="{{ style.href }}" type="text/css" rel="{{ style.rel }}" media="{{ style.media }}" />
{% endfor %}
{% for script in scripts %}
<script src="{{ script }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endfor %}
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% for link in links %}
<link href="{{ link.href }}" rel="{{ link.rel }}" />
{% endfor %}
{% for analytic in analytics %}
{{ analytic }}
{% endfor %}
</head>
<body>
<nav id="top">
<div class="container">{{ currency }}
{{ language }}
<div id="top-links" class="nav pull-right">
<ul class="list-inline">
<li><a href="{{ contact }}"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ telephone }}</span></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ account }}" title="{{ text_account }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ text_account }}</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        {% if logged %}
        <li><a href="{{ account }}">{{ text_account }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ order }}">{{ text_order }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ transaction }}">{{ text_transaction }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ download }}">{{ text_download }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ logout }}">{{ text_logout }}</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ register }}">{{ text_register }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ login }}">{{ text_login }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{{ wishlist }}" id="wishlist-total" title="{{ text_wishlist }}"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ text_wishlist }}</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ shopping_cart }}" title="{{ text_shopping_cart }}"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ text_shopping_cart }}</span></a></li>
<li><a href="{{ checkout }}" title="{{ text_checkout }}"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ text_checkout }}</span></a></li>
{% if logged %}
<li>{{ text_logged }}</li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<header>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div id="logo">
{% if logo %}
<a href="{{ home }}"><img src="{{ logo }}" title="{{ name }}" alt="{{ name }}" class="img-responsive" /></a>
{% else %}
<h1><a href="{{ home }}">{{ name }}</a></h1>
{% endif %}</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">{{ search }}</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">{{ cart }}</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
{{ menu }}
```

The Result:
[opencart-welcome-message-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEEpz.jpg)